# How to replace the escape character in R?

Tags: r, escaping

This might be a silly question, but is it possible to globally change the escape character in R?  The escape character is a single backslash, but my question is, is there any way to obtain control of base R to specify some other character as the escape; for example a tilde "~" or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that is possible short of modifying the source of R but if you explain why you want to do that and give an example of the situation where you would find it useful then alternative solutions to the problem not involving that might exist.

Comment: Thanks, @G.Grothendieck.  I figured that was probably the case.  I just hate having the backslash as my escape character given how prevalent the default escape character is in my data and in my source code when using filenames.  If there was an option to change this, I certainly would as a tilde almost never appears in any of my work, but backslashes are found all over the place.

Comment: how about using `sed` before you load the data, or `gsub` if that's not possible?

Comment: If the issue is filenames, even in Windows you can use the forward bar, `/`. For instance, if you are running R  on Windows `path/to/file` is as valid as `path\\to\\file`.

Comment: If it is in the data you don't need to escape the backslashes in the first place.  `read.table` or `readLines` will read it fine.  If it pertains to writing out file paths then R accepts forward slashes as an alternative to backslashes in filenames even on Windows.  Also you can use the `file.path` function in which case you won't need forward or backward slashes.

Comment: I have backslashes everywhere --- in the data, in my source code, you name it.  So none of the solutions proposed will really do what I was hoping.  I was just hoping there was a way to set an option, without having to start digging into the source code.  It doesn't make a lot of sense for me to start modifying everything in my source code, when a simple option could avoid this.  It looks like it's not possible at the moment.  This may be a new project for me.  Thanks for everyone's responses!